# Replacing values of specific entries in an Array In Julia

Tags: arrays, indexing, julia

I am wondering about how to implement efficiently a code that replaces some entries of an array with specific values. In other words, I have a matrix and a vector with some indices of the matrix where a logical condition holds. I want to change these entries for some values that I have in a vector.

So far, I've doing it with a loop, but perhaps there is a better strategy that uses filtering or something like that.

A small example would be:

```
A = collect(1:8); println(A)
   B = [10,20]
   C = A.<=2
   k = 1
   for t=1:8
                if C[t] ==  1
                    A[t] = B[k]
                    k = k+1
            else
       end
    end
```

However, I need to do this in inside a quite intensive loop, with a bigger matrix. The indices I have to change are always the same, but the vector of values (the counterpart of B) changes in each iteration.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply write:

```
A = collect(1:8)
B = [10,20]
C = findall(A.<=2)
A[C] = B
```

The use of `findall` function could be also rewritten as `C = findall(x -> x <= 2, A)` to reduce the number of allocations. The key is that it is better that `C` holds actual indices than logical indices. Technically `A[C] = B` would also accept logical indices in `C` but then it is slower. And assuming that `C` is computed once while `A[C] = B` is computed many times it is better to precompute the indices you want to use.

If `C` changes with every iteration then it might be better to write `C .= A .<= 2` and then `A[C] = B` (note that I use in-pace update of `C` here as when it is updated many times it is faster). You would have to benchmark what is better in your specific case.

Comment: Wouldn't a loop or a `foreach` (also using `@inbounds`) be probably better for the case in which `C` changes with every iteration?

Comment: Good point. It probably would as in `C .= A .<= 2` and `A[C] = B` we effectively run the loop twice. I wanted to retain the original structure of the code from the question with `A`, `B` and `C`.